# Which integers $a, b, c$ satisfy the equation $a \sqrt 2 − b = c \sqrt5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

This is a non-calculator question:

> Which integers $a, b, c$ satisfy the equation $a \sqrt 2 − b = c \sqrt5$?

I've tried solving it through trial and error and the only solution I seem to be getting is $0,0,0$.

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this problem?

Comment: A practice admissions test for Maths undergrad

Comment: @RaziehNoori It isn't immediately obvious that $a\sqrt{2} - c \sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 5$ are linearly independent over the field of rational $\mathbb Q$; hence the integers satisfying the equality are given by $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: what's a field of rational Q? @Ataulfo

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 5$ are "vectors" of some vectorial space whose scalars are the rational, noted $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us assume there are $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z},ac \neq 0$ such that $a \sqrt 2 − b = c \sqrt5$

$$b=a\sqrt{2} -c\sqrt{5}$$
$$b^2=2a^2+5c^2-2ac\sqrt{10}$$
$$\sqrt{10}=\frac{2a^2+5c^2-b^2}{2ac}$$
$$\implies \sqrt{10} \space \text{is rational (contradiction)}$$

EDIT: As suggested by A.P., we will need to rule out the cases when $a=0$ and when $c=0$ for a complete solution.

When $a=0$,

$$\sqrt{5}=-\frac b{c} \space \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$

When $c=0$,

$$\sqrt{2}=\frac b{a} \space \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$

Comment: This isn't enough. You should note that $a = 0$ or $c = 0$ can't work, either.

Comment: You want to assume that $ac\ne 0$...

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, this answer isn't complete because it doesn't rule out solutions of the form $(0,b,c)$ or $(a,b,0)$. It isn't hard to do so, but you should nonetheless.

Comment: @A.P. thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: square both sides of the equation and remember that $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt5$ are irrational.